# Colorbox doesn't seem to work with inline div

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, html, inline, colorbox

I've a question about Colorbox.

I'm trying to load an inline div in a colorbox. I've literally copy-pasted the code from the example page that comes with it and it simply won't work - I have no idea why; the page loads correctly, the colorbox opens, but there's no content inside it. I'm using MVC with a header, index and footer views, with the script on the header view and the inline on the index view (the link which calls the colorbox is on the header view). Any idea why it could not be working?

(Also, I've tried some other code that makes the colorbox open on page load and that works as expected.)

Comment: Can you give an example fiddle or something?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm a moron. Got it, feel stupid right now. :)

Comment: how is this question related to MVC design pattern in any shape or form ?

Answer (score 0):

Your html should be like this. Note: div with display none first

and then your content div

```
    <div style="display: none"><div id="contentDiv">test content  </div></div>
```